# haproxy - status page for all vhosts except specific ip's

Tags: apache, redirect, haproxy

So i am trying to setup a status page for everyone who tries to access a web server with multiple ip's while we migrate it from centos 5. (no SNI) The user doesn't want to make a dns change and consolidate ip's just yet but we need to migrate them. Is there a way to use haproxy 1.6.3 to have anyone who visits the Apache server goto one vhost and anyone in an acl list get passed straight though? Below is what i have so far but i'm not sure if i'm on the right track.

```
frontend www
    bind *:80
    bind *:443
    mode tcp
    acl disallowed src *
    acl network_allowed src 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2
    use_backend status if disallowed
    use_backend normal if network_allowed

backend status

backend normal
```

Comment: Not sure where the "multiple IPs" come into play.  If Apache is binding to different addresses for SSL purposes, you're going to need a back-end or at least a server declaration for each one of those, and then have apache (assuming it's running on this same machine) listen on an alternate port, where your server declarations will point to.  The easier solution, by far, sounds like it would be to build the new server, backhaul the connections through a proxy to the old server, and change the DNS to point to the new server... but I'm not sure I'm clear on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: centos 5 does not allow SNI in apache the way we have it configured and they had to use a different ip per vhost. what we need to do is send any external user that does not have an ip in the whitelist to a status page letting them know there is maintenance and anyone in the whitelist on to apache as normal. some sites are http and some are https. this is all on the same machine. If there is another way than haproxy to do this that would be welcome as well but without editing each of the 30 vhosts i haven't found any other potential way.